# Angular - When click the edit button load creating form (another component) with the previous data and update button? how can I do it?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an employee list table in the employee-list component. In the table, there is an option to edit details.

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="../create-employee">Edit</button>
```

When clicking the edit button I want to load create employee form (another component) with the update button. As well as I want to load the existing data in the employee to that form? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a link to a different component for this.
Because even though you think "Edit" and "Create" is almost the same, it is **not** the same.

- some fields will not be editable
- create has empty fields, edit has values in them
- the text of the submit-button will be different
- and the APIs will be different as well.

So I would recommend to create an `EditEmployeeComponent`

#### Navigating away

Use the `click` event of your button to call a function that performs the redirect. The actual redirect can then be done as follows:

```
this.router.navigate(["update-employee", selectedEmployeeID]);
```

You'll need to define the `router` variable in your constructor of course.

```
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
constructor (private router: Router) {}
```

The result is that you will be navigated to a path that looks like `/update-employee/1341341` where you put the ID of the record in the URL. That way the next `EditEmployeeComponent` can extract it.

#### Routing to the right component

You probably already somewhere have a "routing file". e.g. `app.routing.module.ts` That's the file where you need to add a new path.

You need to map your "update-employee" URL to your new component (to `EditEmployeeComponent`. The exact code for this depends a little where your component will be situated. (e.g. it could be in a different module)

```
  {
    path: "update-employee/:id",
    loadChildren: ... // point this to your new component
  },
```

#### Extract the id from the URL in your component.

Then inside your new component extract the query parameter and use it to find the details of the employee.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.routeListener = this.route.params.subscribe(async (params) => {
      const employeeId = params["id"];
      this.employee = await this.employeeService.getEmployee(employeeID);
    });
  }
```

In your constructor you need to define the `route` variable though.

```
  constructor(
    private employeeService: EmployeeService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {}
```

To actually retrieve the details of the employee, you can put that in an `EmployeeService`. That would make sense.

*PS: I assume you may already have an `EmployeeService`, after all, you already have a create-employee form, which uses similar APIs. It would make sense that those are already in an `EmployeeService`.*

#### Display data in form

Finally, you'll need to extract the details of the employee, put them in a form. Then add a submit button to save the details. That's a different topic. There are multiple ways to accomplish this. And you probably want to reuse some code of your existing `CreateEmployeeComponent`. You may want to read [more about Angular forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview).

Comment: I did this in separate components. But I got this error .   core.mjs:6484 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')    How can I fix it?

Comment: @NipunaHettiwatta it means that there is a bug in your code somewhere. It tries to read the `id` field, but there is no object to read it from. It is caused by a variable which unexpectedly has an `undefined` value. First you need to find where in your code it happens, before you can find the cause or solution. e.g. it could be the `params` parameter perhaps. If that is the case, you could put a `console.log("value of params: " + params)` in the function and then check the log of your web browser. It could be that or something else, that is why you need to debug your code to find the location.